# Is the tensor by an invertible sheaf functor fully faithful?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My question arises while trying to prove that given a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $F$ and an invertible locally free sheaf of rank $1$ (line bundle) $L$, then $H^0(X,F\otimes L^n)\cong Hom(L^{-n},F).$

Here $L^n$ denotes the $n$-th tensor power of $L$, and the minus sign indicates its inverse in the Picard group of $X$. I'd like to prove that using the tensor-Hom adjunction and other two facts that maybe very simple but I'm not so sure about. My attempt would be so to consider isomorphisms
$$Hom(-,Hom(L^{-n},F))\cong Hom(L^{-n}\otimes -,F)\cong Hom(-,L^n\otimes F)\cong Hom(-,H^0(X,L^n\otimes F)),$$
and eventually use Yoneda embedding. Are the two last step correct? That is $(i)$ tensor product functor $L\otimes -$ is fully faithful and $(ii)$ there is isomorphism between groups $Hom_{\mathcal{O_{X}}}(-,G)$ and $Hom_{Ab}(-,G(X))$ for a sheaf of modules $G$? If so, how to prove them? If not, how to prove the original statement?

Really thanks in advance :)

Comment: This does not make any sense some of your hom are between a sheaf and a group. and realy all you need is to under stand $H^0$ as global sections then try to write global sections as morphism between two sheaf

Comment: Tensoring by an invertible sheaf is an equivalence of categories (with inverse given by tensoring by the dual - that’s why they’re called *invertible* sheaves), so in particular fully faithful.

Comment: Thank you both @ali and @Qiaochu! Now I get it, I’m going to use the group isomorphism $Hom_O(O,F)=H^0(X,F)$ given by analogy with the isomorphism $Hom_{Rmod}(R,M)=M$ that take a morphism $f$ to $f(1)$ (in the sheaf-case will take $f$ to $f_X(1)$). Then I tensor by the invertibile sheaf preserving Homs, is that correct?

Comment: no, I can’t have injectivity in this way: I think the mapping should be of $f$ to the gluing of the compatible family $\{f_U(1)\in F(U)\}$